# Remove White Flicker in Image when loading flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-gridview

I'm building an app which shows hundreds of images in grid view. In grid tile, I showed low-quality images. when we press the image I showed the full quality image, In the meantime, I'm showing the low-quality image as a placeholder. I'm using the `CachedNetworkImage` package. Problem here is when the full quality image loads there is some white flicker as shown as [here](https://ibb.co/VxKDdVV). I want to remove that flickr. Is there any way to remove that one ?

Here is my code.

```
 Widget cachedImage(imageUrl) {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                      blurRadius: 2,
                      offset: Offset(2, 2))
                ],
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: imageProvider,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          ),
      placeholder: (context, url) => LoadingWidget1(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Center(child: Icon(Icons.error)),
    );
  }

//code for thumbnail image
Hero(
    tag: 'category$index',
    child: cachedImage(d['thumbnail url'])
),

//Code for FullQuality Preview

....
child: CachedNetworkImage(
                placeholderFadeInDuration: Duration(microseconds: 0),
                useOldImageOnUrlChange: true,
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                ),

                placeholder: (context, url) => Stack(
                  children: [

                    CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: thumbUrl,
                      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover)),

                    ),

                  ),
```

Comment: The link that shows the flicker is returning a 404.

Comment: I updated the link.

Comment: Try increasing the fade in duration to something like a second and see if the issue becomes more obvious. Might be a one mil fade is looking weird.

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't make any changes. Even if I don't want to hide that, can I able to show circularprogrss indicator for one second above the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're 2 fade durations in [CachedNetworkImage](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/blob/develop/cached_network_image/lib/src/cached_image_widget.dart) with default values being non null (`placeholderFadeInDuration` is null by the way), you can try zeroing both `fadeOutDuration` and `fadeInDuration`:

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution. Still, it is not solved. Nothing changed

Comment: The other suspect is the transition animation. Not sure how you implemented switching of screens, yet you might want to check route animations (https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation) or any other custom code which navigates to a certain wallpaper after clicking on a card.

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured out and solved by adjusting duration as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You might want setting `PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.maximumSizeBytes = 1000 << 20;` in `main()`, as suggested [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/325)